# Change settings of brackets layout in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, styles, brackets

When I create a new class, enum, etc.. Eclipse automatically puts the bracket next to the declaration of the class, but I would like to see it automatically in a new line.

So when I create the class I would like to aspect something like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{

}
```

and not this

```
public class MyClass {

}
```

does anybody know how to change this setting?

Comment: Open `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`. Edit your active profile (or create a new one) and look at the `Braces` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `Windows > Preferences` go to `Java > Code Style > Formatter`. Click on Edit button for the active formatter. Change the option as shown below.

[image]

[image]